# How to nest multilevel model (or to nest at all)?

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, multilevel-analysis

I'm trying to handle some data and get some insights from it.

The data includes a binary outcome variable, so I am using glmer.

The relationship is whether age groups are more likely to engage in the outcome variable. The issue is that many participants have multiple observations, over a time span of about two years.

I've created a model that includes participant ID as a random effect, which is good.

`glmer(Modality ~ Age_Quartile + (1|pt_number), family = "binomial", data = tel)`

The issue I'm running into is including time. I'm not sure if I want to include it at all, but it seems that the relationship seems to switch at a point in time (based on some EDA), so I feel it should be included. However, I'm not sure if it should be put in as a separate random effect, or if it should be nested in the participant ID, and if so, which direction the nesting should be.

Options:

Separate effect:

`glmer(Modality ~ Age_Quartile + (1|pt_number) + (1|monthnum), family = "binomial", data = tel)`

Time nested within ID:

`glmer(Modality ~ Age_Quartile + (1|pt_number/monthnum), family = "binomial", data = tel)`

ID nested within time:

`glmer(Modality ~ Age_Quartile + (1|monthnum/pt_number), family = "binomial", data = tel)`

I appreciate any help, and I apologize if my question is too vague.

Thank you!

Comment: Good question.  I'm curious to see answers; my instinct would have been to include time as a fixed effect if I supposed that the time factor would not vary from person to person.  Do you think time matters globally or within each person's set of records?